# Retrieving Data from FireBase SWIFT

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm trying to get data out of a firebase database if the addedByUser = a value stored in the application.

With what I currently have, nothing is appearing in the table.

The firebase database looks like this:

workout1
   "name"
   "addedByUser"

My code looks like this:

```
workout3Ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            var newWorkout = [Workout1Info]()
            for item in snapshot.children {
                let createdBy = snapshot.value["addedByUser"] as? String
                if createdBy == Username.sharedInstance.userDetail {
                    let workoutItem = Workout1Info(snapshot: item as! FDataSnapshot)
                    newWorkout.append(workoutItem)
                }
            }
            self.workouts = newWorkout
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

When I get data normally without comparing if the addedByUser it normally works. Does anyone know why it isn't working?

Thanks for the help

Comment: "get data normally without comparing if the addedByUser"? No idea what that means or is trying to say. Also, "firebase data looks like this," no it doesn't and that's not helpful either. Try https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/path/to/data.json?print=pretty and post that (or some filtered version of it) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess based on a super vague question with some coding issues:

The createdBy is the users name or uid as a string.

The Username.sharedInstance.userDetail is an object (of some kind)

So you are comparing a String to an object that isn't a string, and that won't work.

Also, if the node you are query-ing is the /workout1 node, then you should probably name your reference workout1Ref instead of workout3Ref. That may help keep things straight in code.

Answer (score 0):

- While you are comaparing **`String`** `createdBy` with `Username.sharedInstance.userDetail` check your property `Username.sharedInstance.userDetail` also should be of **`String`** type.